# Is there a way to show unique values with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a Json file with Networking traffic.

It has headers like
'uid', 'orig_IP', 'id.orig_p', 'resp_IP', 'id.resp_p',

```
"id.orig_h":"10.20.57.3","id.orig_p":59580,"id.resp_h":"10.10.2.22","id.resp_p":53,"proto":"udp","service":"dns",
```

In python and with pandas i want to show the number of connections with each unique IP address and the Responding IP address

Like so

```
 Orig IP        Resp IP      Number of times(count)
> 1.2.3.4        3.4.5.6        30
> 4.2.1.3        1.2.3.4        122
> 4.4.4.4        192.1.3.4      79
```

A def reads the json file and makes a df

```
def readZeekFileJson(filename):
    df = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True)
    return df

def readFile(filename):
    if is_exist_file(filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max'])
    return df

def get_stats(df):
        df_stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=statscols)
    
        df = pd.concat([df['id.orig_h'], df['id.resp_h']]).value_counts()
    
       # unique_values = pd.unique(column_values)
        print(df, count)
    
    
        #print(df['id.resp_h'].sort_values().unique())
    
        return df_stats
```

I tried this but it does not give the correct result

result:

```
10.20.57.3                   7108
10.10.2.22                   4238
10.10.2.21                   2851
34.122.121.32                   8
```

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example, this mean a minimal example of the data and the matching expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.